# Trouble Creating Forms in AJAX/Javascript/HTML based upon drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

My job would like a very simple web form that we would use for internal work submissions.  The work submissions would fall into 4 Categories with unique information required for each one.  Now I currently have a simple form that does the following:

Requested Name:   [Text Box]
Requested Date:     [Text Box]
Acquisition:             [Text Box]
Type of Request:    [Drop Down] with 4 Items

What I want is depending upon the drop down item selected the user should see the correct form displayed below.  Which would contain a table form more "Items and text boxes for Input."

Right now I am trying this but I am having multiple issues, i.e. I can only see one table row instead of everything that is selected.

So maybe I am approaching the problem in the wrong way? So I am going to throw myself before you and humbly ask for help.  Either a point in the right direction, or anything at this point!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('select[name="select_main_table"]').change(function() {
      $("#main_table tr").hide().eq(this.value-1).show();
   }).change();
});



      <td><label for="typeofrequest">Type of Request</label></td>
      <td><select name="select_main_table">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> - Choose -</option>
        <option value="1">Office Move</option>
        <option value="2">Office Closure</option>
        <option value="3">New Office</option>
        <option value="4">New Service</option>
      </select>          </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

   <table id="main_table">
    <tr> 
      <td><label for="sitecontactname">Site Contact Name</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[sitecontactname]]" name="sitecontactname" id="sitecontactname" value="" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>  
      <td><label for="sitecontacttitle">Site Contact Title</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[sitecontacttitle]]" name="sitecontacttitle" id="sitecontacttitle" value="" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr> 
      <td><label for="sitecontactemail">Site Contact Email</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[sitecontactemail]]" name="sitecontactemail" id="sitecontactemail" value="" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>  
      <td><label for="sitecontacttelephonenumber">Site Contact Telephone Number</label></td>
      <td><input type="text" class="validate[required,custom[sitecontacttelephonenumber]]" name="sitecontacttelephonenumber" id="sitecontacttelephonenumber" value="" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: why is there part of a table floating in the middle of your code?

Comment: @TomJones: welcome to StackOverflow. I removed the introduction of who you are. If you feel that this is useful information, you can retrieve it from the history and add it to your profile page.

Comment: Keeg - Everything below the function, is a section of code I removed from my project.  I was trying to keep it brief so I pulled out what I believed to be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.  I was able to find some code on another site that led me to a better resolution.